# find minimum length between two node types in gramlin

Tags: python-3.x, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to find out the minimum length between two node type vertex. Let's assumed there are big data set of different node types. M trying to make a generic query, which will work for different node types as well.
I am using python3, gremlin